# Windows DHCP client hostname encoding

Tags: windows, unicode, character-encoding, dhcp

Recently I have been trying to save list of hostnames from captured DHCP packets. I have found out, every **DHCP hostname (option 12)** should have form defined in **RFC 1035**. So if I understand it correctly, hostname should be encoded in 7-bit ASCII and have other restrictions like:
- name should not start with digit and should omit some forbidden characters.

Almost every device I have encountered in packets fulfill this constraint, but not Windows devices (**Vendor ID MSFT 5.0**). IMHO Windows DHCP client takes computer (mobile) name and fill it in hostname option.

Problem occurs, when computer name is set for example to **"Lukáš-PC"**. Wireshark display this hostname as **Luk\240\347-PC**. (240 and 347 are numbers in octal). To see for myself I have printed values in packets  with printf("%hhu", c) (C language).

```
á = 160
š = 231
```

IMHO I think this is simple char variable overflow. I tried deduce original value from overflow value, but I haven't found any relation between character and known encodings. So my questions are:

**Is there any way to convert these values back to original?
If yes, what was original character encoding, when overflow happened?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `char` is usually signed, and extends to `int` when passed to a variadic function. To ensure that it is printed unsigned, use `printf("%hhu", c)` or `printf("%d", (unsigned char)c);`.

The correct encoding is impossible to know because it depends on each system's settings.

Note that any compliant systems **MUST** encode names according to [RFC 3490](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3490), but Windows seems to enjoy violating standards.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have printed characters again and values are:
á = 160
š = 231
I hope I understand what you have written. So there is no way to find out what were original values specifically for Windows operating systems? My idea is to just check  VENDOR_ID == MSFT 5.0 in packet, and somehow convert it back if Windows devices are using same encoding, but I would need to know which encoding Windows uses.

Answer (score 0):

The characters á and š that you are seing are encoded using [code page 852 (Latin-2 - Central European languages)](https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp852.html).

Unfortunately there is no simple way how you can figure out the encoding used only by looking at DHCP requests. In principle the DHCP client can use any code page it wants. If you are working in a private/controlled network, then it is probably safe to assume the all clients are using the same code page and explicitly encode the strings using that particular code page.